# How to generate secret with sufficient iterations on device with little CPU power

Tags: java, encryption, raspberry-pi

Our application runs on a Raspberry Pi and is installed on many places on customer sites. The Pi is cheap and good enough for our purposes. However, we have a problenm that for storing the user's login password on disk generating a secret with something like 50.000 iterations to be reasonably safe takes way too much time on the slow Pi. When the user logs in the password has to be decrypted and those 50.000 iterations have to be executed again which takes minutes on the Pi. The web frontend gets a timeout and the user won't wait for minutes to log in anyway.

My question is whether anyone has an idea how to encrypt and decrypt passwords in a safe way on disk given a CPU with little processing power.

Comment: Can you describe de current design of your authentication process? which algorithms are you using at the moment?

Comment: We use class SecretKeyFactory from javax.crypto with PBE encryption (e.g. PBEKeySpec). The salt is created with SecureRandom.

Comment: Right, you are looking for an alternative to PBE encryption as you noticed, it is not that fast on IoT devices like a raspeberry pi. I was reading this https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48671/how-much-faster-in-symmetric-cryptography-compared-to-asymmetric-cryptography , it might be interesting reading for you. Meanwhile I will investigate this!

Comment: Maybe Java Cryptographic helps you. E.g. https://howtodoinjava.com/java/java-security/how-to-generate-secure-password-hash-md5-sha-pbkdf2-bcrypt-examples/

Comment: The preferred way of hashing passwords is currently Argon2. bcrypt or scrypt are also fine. Unfortunately Java is in this case also a negative factor. Native implementations are a lot faster for high iterations than every Java implementation. If your execution platform is always a Raspberry with Linux you may consider to us a library that implements the password hashing algo as native .so library.

Comment: In production it is always PI running Linux. So calling into some C programm to do the encryption efficiently as can be would be a good idea.

Comment: @Robert `native implementations are a lot faster for high iterations than every Java implementation` this is off topic, anyway I'd say that was true 10 years ago. When JIT catches up, it's almost native speed

Answer (score 2):

> However, we have a problem that for storing the user's login password on disk generating a secret

I hope you mean hashing (non-reversible mangle) the password

> with something like 50.000 iterations to be reasonably safe 
> 50.000 iterations have to be executed again which takes minutes on the Pi

I'm not sure where/how did you get to the 50k number, but in this case it's important to understand the context/reason. The iterations are intended, if the database is leaked, as a way to slow down options for dictionary or brute-force attacks to find passwords, which tends to be weak (short, simple, reused, known).

Effectively you don't need any iteration if you could ensure the user passwords are secure (long, random)  enough.

Indeed on the IoT devices this iteration is tricky, as you cannot compete with hashing farms and tolerable delay (100-300ms) on default servers comes to prohibiting times on low-end devices.

> My question is whether anyone has an idea how ... given a CPU with little processing power.

I see two options

- Make the number of iteration reasonable. Yes, it lowers the security margin for brute/dictionary attacks, but you can make up to the level using the strong user passwords
- If the password is intended for authentication to a web application, you could delegate the authentication to a 3rd party service (Azure AD, AWS Cognito, IBM AppId, OAuth0, Okta, ... ), there are plenty of free or not-so-free services.

Comment: "I hope you mean hashing (non-reversible mangle) the password". Yes we store the hash :-)

Comment: "I'm not sure where/how did you get to the 50k number". There are some article by crypto experts that 50k or 60k or more iterations make the hash very safe.

Comment: "If the password is intended for authentication to a web application, you could delegate the authentication to a 3rd party service". That is a good idea. The Pis are connected to some powerfull server that process the data the Pis are sending. If the connection to the mqtt broker is down, there is a problem though. Maybe have local decryption running then in that case using a hash created with fewer iterations. But then the hash for local decryption needs to be created from a different password to be safe.

Comment: @OlliP my idea is using e.g. OAuth2 and let completely different service handle the authentication.

Comment: @OlliP creating an (de)encryption key and authenticating may be different, do not mix it. It is usually bad idea to use the user passwords for encryption (when the users forgets its password, data are lost).

Answer (score 0):

Haveged will do the job in this case. Just let it run for a while and it will generate enough entropy.